# Passing 2D arrays to a function to print out a matrice

Tags: c++, arrays, function, multidimensional-array

I want to make a program, in which I pass a 2D array to a function, and the function prints the contents of the array in a matrix format. However, in my code, the function is printing only 1, also why am I getting the following warning "pointer to a function used in arithmetic"?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void grid(int size[][3]){
    
    for(int x=0;x<3;x++){
        for(int y=0;y<3;y++){
            cout<<grid[x][y];
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
int main(){

    
    int mak[3][3]={
    {1,2,3},
    {4,5,6},
    {7,8,9}
    };
        grid(mak);
    }
```

Comment: `cout << size[x][y];`????

Comment: Do not change your question once posted.. You can ADD to it at the bottom. Otherwise, all comments and answers before you change your question no longer make sense.

Comment: You define the function to take a matrix called `size`: `void grid(int size[][3])` and then try to print the function called `grid` as if it were a matrix.  So `cout<<grid[x][y];` should be `cout<<size[x][y];`